# Rubyで2つの配列の差分をさっさと知る方法（集合）

Tags: ruby

ベン図みたいのを知りたい時

```rb
p (array1 | array2).size
p (array1 & array2).size
p (array1 - (array1 & array2)).size
p (array2 - (array1 & array2)).size
```

ってやってるけど、もっと賢い方法を知らないだけの気がしています。
なにかオススメの方法はありますでしょうか？

また、配列が2つ以上のときでもオススメの方法とかもありますか？

Comment: 集合の和・差・共通部分のサイズだけ知れれば良いということでしょうか？　要素を知る必要は無いというので合っていますか？

Comment: 配列が3つ以上の時は `[array1, array2, array3].inject(:&)`(積集合) とか `[array1, array2, array3].inject(:|)`(和集合) ですかね。

Comment: なるほど。`inject` でいけるんですね。

Comment: 和集合の`union` 差集合の `difference` なんていうのもあるんですね。`intersection`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

とりあえず「集合 `a` に含まれていて集合 `b` に含まれない要素の数」を求めるのに `(a - (a & b)).size` は冗長で、

```
(a - b).size
```

とするだけで求まります。

Comment: 知らなかったです。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

配列が3つ以上の時は `[array1, array2, array3].inject(:&)`(積集合) とか `[array1, array2, array3].inject(:|)`(和集合) ですかね。

<sub>-- この回答は、[metroplis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis) さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61506/ruby%E3%81%A72%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AE%E9%85%8D%E5%88%97%E3%81%AE%E5%B7%AE%E5%88%86%E3%82%92%E3%81%95%E3%81%A3%E3%81%95%E3%81%A8%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95-%E9%9B%86%E5%90%88/61514#comment66977_61506)をコミュニティ wiki として回答化したものです。</sub>